# Accessing data from a SqlDataProvider

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm using the SQlProvider in a project to query a database and perform CRUD operations.  I come from C#/Entity-Framework background, so my normal approach would be to use a [generic repository](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle).  The advantages to this approach is that it eliminates redundant code for CRUD operations across entity types.

I'm looking for a similar approach to take while using the [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/).  I can query from individual tables fine, but I'm not sure how I would go about creating a DAL in a generic manner.  Any suggestions on how I shoud approach creating a generic DAL?

Comment: I'm not really sure you need that. You do need to setup your types that match the table but after that you can query and write back to the table. Can you show a concrete or pseudo example you want to simplify?

Comment: Patterns like *Repository* exist in mainstream object-oriented languages as a remedy for those languages' lack of support for decoupling decisions from effects. In F# you can do just that: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/09/26/decoupling-decisions-from-effects While I'd use something like a Repository in C#, I don't need it in F#.

Comment: Even in C# IQueryable<T> drastically reduces the usefulness of Repository. What's the point of `GetAll` or GetById` when you can pass a lambda to filter or select using the object's semantics?

Comment: Perhaps I was incorrect to conflate the DAL with the generic aspects of that particular pattern with entity framework.  I have several dozen tables I need to query against, and in entity framework they have DbSet<T>, which is nice because it provides generic access to all entities.  I'm looking to implement something similar in F# so I don't find myself writing the same getById query dozens of times.  One thought I had was to define a union across my provided types, but once the number of types grows significantly, the pattern matching code becomes quite cumbersome.